# SSRS : Report with multiple queries with paramters from first query

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a db table that looks like this:

PurchaseID  | ItemName  |  ItemColor  |  PurchaseDate

```
1       | Car       |  blue       | 11-03-12
2       | Plane     | red         | 12-03-12
3       | Car       | green       | 11-03-12
```

I need an report that provide following info:

ItemName (distinguished)  | Number of purchases before @DateX(parameter from user)  |  Amount of green items purchased  |

I can fill first column with all distinguished item names, but have no idea what to do with others...

As far as I know it's not possible to insert an SQL query to expression (is it so?).
I'm not very experienced in SQL, maybe it's possible to fill all report columns with single query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an if statement inside a sum aggregate. Grouped by `ItemName`, columns are:

- `=Fields!ItemName.Value`
- `=Sum(IIf(Fields!PurchaseDate.Value < Parameters!DateX.Value, 1, 0))`
- `=Sum(IIf(Fields!ItemColor = "green", 1, 0))`

Comment: wow! Thanx lc! Is it possible to take item names from Items table and then fill other columns with purchases data from Purchases table? In this way items with no purchases will be also present in report. I'm sorry for adding more requirement to my first post...

Comment: You'll have to do this from the database using a join.

Comment: @Anton Make sure your grouping is right, it sounds like you're doing this on a details row with no grouping and thus Sum is only counting one row